# BlueOcean is showing green steps even when Pipeline is broken

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I am using Jenkins Declarative syntax to define my pipeline.

My pipeline is broken in my Sonar Quality Gate and all the stages are skipped but the latest one is showing green denoting successful.

Is this an issue with the BlueOcean Plugin or I am doing something wrong:

### BlueOcean View

[image]

### My Code

```
pipeline{
    agent { label 'maven-build-slave' }
    options { 
        skipDefaultCheckout()
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5')) 
    }
    stages{
        stage("Checkout Project"){
            steps{
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Unit Test & Build Application') {
            steps{
                buildApplication()        
            }
        }
        stage("Sonar Quality & Security"){
            steps{
                sonarScanner()
                sonarAnalysis()
            } 
        }
        stage('Checkout JBoss Binaries') {
            steps{
                checkoutBinaries()
            }
        }
        stage('Pull WARs') {
            steps{
                copyBuildArtifacts()
            }
        }
        stage('Pull Configuration') {
            steps{
                pullConfiguration()
            }
        }
        stage('Configure Vaults') {
            steps{
                configureVaults()
            }
        }
        stage('Configure Secrets') {
            steps{
                configureConfigMap()
            }
        }
        stage('Configure Properties') {
            steps{
                configureBuildConfig()
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy Image') {
            steps{
                configureAndDeploy()
            }
        }
        stage("Integration Tests"){
            parallel {
                stage("Integration (REST API)"){
                    steps{
                        runIntegrationTestsRest()
                    }
                }
                stage("Integration (Workflow)"){ 
                    steps{
                        runIntegrationTestsWorkflow()
                    }
                }
                stage("Integration (SoapUI)"){
                    agent { label 'jenkins-slave-soapui' }
                    steps{
                        runIntegrationTestSoapUi()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post{
        always{
            script{
                sendNotification status: currentBuild.result, 
                                 subject: "Deployment Completed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Jenkins logs

The Jenkins logs show the rest of the stages that were skipped:

```
Stage 'Checkout JBoss Binaries' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Pull WARs)
Stage 'Pull WARs' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Pull Configuration)
Stage 'Pull Configuration' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Configure Vaults)
Stage 'Configure Vaults' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Configure Secrets)
Stage 'Configure Secrets' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Configure Properties)
Stage 'Configure Properties' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy Image)
Stage 'Deploy Image' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Integration Tests)
Stage 'Integration Tests' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [Integration (REST API)] { (Branch: Integration (REST API))
[Pipeline] [Integration (Workflow)] { (Branch: Integration (Workflow))
[Pipeline] [Integration (SoapUI)] { (Branch: Integration (SoapUI))
[Pipeline] [Integration (REST API)] stage
[Pipeline] [Integration (REST API)] { (Integration (REST API))
[Pipeline] [Integration (Workflow)] stage
[Pipeline] [Integration (Workflow)] { (Integration (Workflow))
[Pipeline] [Integration (SoapUI)] stage
[Pipeline] [Integration (SoapUI)] { (Integration (SoapUI))
Stage 'Integration (REST API)' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
Stage 'Integration (Workflow)' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
Stage 'Integration (SoapUI)' skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] [Integration (REST API)] }
[Pipeline] [Integration (Workflow)] }
[Pipeline] [Integration (SoapUI)] }
[Pipeline] [Integration (REST API)] // stage
[Pipeline] [Integration (Workflow)] // stage
[Pipeline] [Integration (SoapUI)] // stage
[Pipeline] [Integration (REST API)] }
[Pipeline] [Integration (Workflow)] }
[Pipeline] [Integration (SoapUI)] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
```

Any ideas?

I would like to see the Integration Test Stage as empty also. I didn't run the tests at all, the only issue here is the green color is essentially a false-positive for my pipeline.

Comment: That sounds like https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47219.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour, did you ever get to the bottom of it?